# Calculated Field to see if point is greater than Standard Deviation

Tags: tableau-api

So instead of having a SUM of all the amounts per person, I now instead have a Circle View of all the amounts they have spent (each circle being a transaction).

Now, I need to create a calculated field to see if a transaction is above the standard deviation of ALL transactions (hence making it an outlier).

Any way you can help me create a calculated field? I keep getting errors.

My Calculated Field formula went something like this

```
If [AMOUNT] > STDEV([AMOUNT]) THEN "bad"
ELSE "good"
END
```

[My Data Points Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYNsW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix aggregate  and non-aggregate arguements. You need to use an LOD (Level of Detail) expression in this case. Below is a valid calculation.

```
If [AMOUNT] > {STDEV([AMOUNT])} THEN "bad"
ELSE "good"
END
```

You can change the expression based on the Level Of detail required. Please refer to this [article](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html) for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Put curly braces {} around the second expression, but not the first.

```
if [AMOUNT] > { STDEV([AMOUNT]) } then ...
```

To understand why, read about LOD calculations in the online help